# Is it possible to view objects within a layer in Inkscape?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, inkscape, adobe-fireworks

In Fireworks, or Photoshop, or GIMP your layer list also includes the objects within each layer. I've just started exploring Inkscape and can't seem to find this functionality. Some googling reveals a few people asking for this feature 5 or 6 years ago but nothing recent.

Can I view objects in Inkscape outside of the raw XML viewer?

```
Layer Trees
 > Oak
 > Red Maple
 > dPine
 > Palm
Layer Structures
 > Barn
 > Driveway
 > Mailbox
```

Ideally I'd be able to show/hide and lock/unlock objects within that window just like you can in PS, FW, and GIMP...

Thank you.

Answer (score 20):

Inkscape 0.92 introduced the [objects dialog](https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Release_notes/0.92#Objects_Dialog) which should be exactly what you want. You can open it in the menu at "Object > Objects...".

[image: objects dialog]

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at [Inkscape for Adobe Illustrator users](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Inkscape_for_Adobe_Illustrator_users#Layers).

> Inkscape's layers are accessible as a drop-down menu in the Status bar, with the lock and visibility toggles beside it affecting the current layer. An artist can select the layer from the list, and then select its visibility and lock status. Alternatively, use the Layers dialog (Ctrl+Shift+L).

But this shows layers only with show/hide and lock/unlock options, not as a list of objects.

The answer to your question: No.

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>

shows you the **XML Editor**, which is a basic version of exactly that. You can also manipulate XML values and see an expandable object tree.

Source: https://inkscape.org/en/doc/tutorials/advanced/tutorial-advanced.en.html

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can do is search for an object ID (`Edit>Find`) and then use the `Object>Object properties` menu to hide and/or lock.

Search can be performed in the current layer only.

Comment: [This post](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/75509/how-can-i-find-hidden-object-in-inkscape/75510#75510) explains how to find hidden objects in Inkscape